S3 server simulation in FastAPI, Python
I want to implement S3 server using FastAPI and Python. This is my code for signature validation:
async def verify_signature(request: Request):
  try:
    authorization_header = request.headers.get("Authorization")
    amz_date = request.headers.get("x-amz-date")
    if not authorization_header or not amz_date:
        logging.error("Missing authorization or x-amz-date header")
        return False
    logging.debug(f"\n\n=======================================================\n")
    logging.debug(f"Request URL:\n{request.url}")
    logging.debug(f"Authorization Header:\n{authorization_header}")
    logging.debug(f"x-amz-date:\n{amz_date}")

    auth_parts = authorization_header.split(", ")
    credential_part = auth_parts[0]
    signed_headers_part = auth_parts[1]
    signature_part = auth_parts[2]

    credential_scope = (
        credential_part.split(" ")[1].split("Credential=")[1].split("/")[1:]
    )
    credential_scope = "/".join(credential_scope)

    signed_headers = signed_headers_part.split("SignedHeaders=")[-1].split(";")
    provided_signature = signature_part.split("Signature=")[-1]

    logging.debug(f"Signed Headers:\n{signed_headers}")
    logging.debug(f"Credential Scope:\n{credential_scope}")

    headers_dict = {k.lower(): v for k, v in request.headers.items()}
    sorted_headers = {
        k: headers_dict[k] for k in sorted(headers_dict) if k in signed_headers
    }

    logging.debug(f"Headers Dict:\n{headers_dict}")
    logging.debug(f"Sorted Headers:\n{sorted_headers}")

    canonical_uri = request.url.path
    canonical_querystring = request.url.query
    if False and headers_dict.get("x-amz-content-sha256") == "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD":
        payload_hash = (
            "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
        )
    else:
        payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(await request.body()).hexdigest()

    sorted_headers["x-amz-content-sha256"] = payload_hash
    canonical_headers = "".join([f"{k}:{v}\n" for k, v in sorted_headers.items()])

    canonical_request = "\n".join(
        [
            request.method,
            canonical_uri,
            canonical_querystring,
            canonical_headers,
            ";".join(signed_headers),
            payload_hash,
        ]
    )

    logging.debug(f"Canonical Request:\n{canonical_request}")

    string_to_sign = "\n".join(
        [
            ALGORITHM,
            amz_date,
            credential_scope,
            hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(),
        ]
    )

    logging.debug(f"String to Sign:\n{string_to_sign}")

    date_stamp = credential_scope.split("/")[0]
    signing_key = get_signature_key(
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        date_stamp,
        AWS_REGION,
        SERVICE,
    )

    signature = hmac.new(
        signing_key, string_to_sign.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()

    logging.debug(f"Calculated Signature: {signature}")
    logging.debug(f"Provided Signature: {provided_signature}")

    is_valid = provided_signature == signature
    if not is_valid:
        logging.error("Signatures do not match")
    return is_valid

  except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Verification failed: {e}")
    return False

This is how I test:
def test():
    from io import BytesIO

    import boto3

    session = boto3.Session(
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region_name=AWS_REGION
    )
    client = session.client(
        "s3", endpoint_url=ENDPOINT
    )
    f = BytesIO(b"salam2")
    f.seek(0)
    put_res = client.put_object(Bucket="mybucket", Key="myfile2.txt", Body=f)
    print(put_res)
    get_res = client.get_object(Bucket="mybucket", Key="myfile2.txt")
    print(get_res["Body"].read())
    del_res = client.delete_object(Bucket="mybucket", Key="myfile2.txt")
    print(del_res)

The code works correctly for GET and DELETE requests. But the calculated signature for PUT is not matched.
Any help?
I have tried many ways, I have read this link:
https://czak.pl/2015/09/15/s3-rest-api-with-curl.html#step_1
I have asked chatgpt
And this is amazon documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html
